# Page can scroll past body width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Having an issue with this page that on iPhone 6 you can scroll to the right and see white space. I tried making everything set to width 100% and overflow-x is hidden. I also put this in the header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

This is the link http://chkpt.com.au/iPhone-X/index.html sorry the site looks like spam it's for a client.

To see it you need to click one of the buttons on the first page and it will transition to a form then scroll to the right.

I just replicated in the native "internet" app on my android, does not occur in chrome. Happens in all browsers on iOS.

Comment: Where do you see the issue? Doesn't appear to me

Comment: In chrome mobile inspect it is fine. I can't test on iOS.

Comment: I can only get it to occur using iOS device natively, I couldn't replicate it on my pc. Also sorry I forgot to mention you need to click on of the buttons on the first screen so it transitions to a form then you will see it.

Comment: You can reproduce with latest version of desktop Safari, just restrict the width of the browser. Have you tried setting `html { overflow: hidden; }`? A better approach might be to figure out what element is forcing the horizontal scroll, and fixing that, but setting overflow hidden on `html` is a quick fix. Already verified it works.